# Отправка части строки в сеть

Tags: java

Имеем сокет, с ним имеем `DataInputStream` и `DataOutputStream`. Так-же есть `BufferedReader`, который читает текст из файла, но через `out.writeUTF` передать прочитанную строку не выходит, т.к. она слишком большая. Такой вопрос, можно ли сделать буфер для чтения, к примеру в 10кб за раз?

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` нетрудно заменить на `BufferedInputStream` и тогда всё можно очень просто сделать:

```
protected long copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    long bytesWritten = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        if (bytesRead > 0) os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesWritten += bytesRead;
    }
    return bytesWritten;
}
```